# How can I fix the unsecure_base_url on my Magento installation?

Tags: database, magento, config, skin

I've been having problems with uploading images and in trying to fix it, happened to change the base_url in the config which has now caused my website to appear without any styling at all (inc the Admin).

I've gone into phpMyAdmin and fixed the urls but i'm not having any luck. This is what i've got at the moment...

```
web/unsecure/base_link_url   http://www.northwalesdoorworld.co.uk/
web/unsecure/base_skin_url   http://www.northwalesdoorworld.co.uk/skin/
web/unsecure/base_media_url   http://www.northwalesdoorworld.co.uk/media/
web/unsecure/base_js_url   http://www.northwalesdoorworld.co.uk/js/
```

Could someone please take a look at my site - northwalesdoorworld.co.uk - and recommend a way to solve my problem?

thanks,
Greg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you can't access your site due that you can change the values directly in core_config_data table

```
SELECT *  FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%web/unsecure%' or path LIKE '%web/secure%'
```

you can fix them by editing the values to be like clockworkgeek suggested or removing whole rows from database and they will be created over again by magneto and you can use the admin page to add new values.

Comment: Thanks so much (both of you!).  I deleted the rows in phpMyAdmin and after deleting the Cache and Session folders, everything is back to normal..........awesome! :-D

Answer (score 3):

Change the four values to:

```
{{unsecure_base_url}}
{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/
{{unsecure_base_url}}media/
{{unsecure_base_url}}js/
```

Empty `var/cache/` in your magento folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the most recent Magento wiki entry: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/restore_base_url_settings

You can also add something like this to /MAGENTO/app/etc/config.xml rather than manipulate the database:

```
<stores>
<default>
<web>
<unsecure>
<base_url>{{base_url}}</base_url>
<base_link_url>{{unsecure_base_url}}</base_link_url>
<base_web_url>{{unsecure_base_url}}</base_web_url>
<base_skin_url>{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/</base_skin_url>
<base_js_url>{{unsecure_base_url}}js/</base_js_url>
<base_media_url>{{unsecure_base_url}}media/</base_media_url>
</unsecure>
<secure>
<base_url>{{base_url}}</base_url>
<base_web_url>{{secure_base_url}}</base_web_url>
<base_link_url>{{secure_base_url}}</base_link_url>
<base_js_url>{{secure_base_url}}js/</base_js_url>
<base_skin_url>{{secure_base_url}}skin/</base_skin_url>
<base_media_url>{{secure_base_url}}media/</base_media_url>
</secure>
</web>
</default>
</stores>
```