# After changing unsecure and secure base url not able to access frontend and backend

Tags: magento

I have change my unsecure and secure base url from admin->config->web but now i am not able to access my site anything please help me to make it change back as my prior base url.

Comment: you need to check `core_config_data` table and revert the value as before.....

Comment: i have done this but its not working

Comment: clear cache once from var/cache folder

Comment: i have also cleared cache and session but not working

Comment: did you checked under `base skin, media, js url` for both `secure & unsecure` ?

Comment: can u please explain your last comment

Comment: check answer below....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `core config_data` table , under column path, you need to check values below these :

if you go for 1st page you will see as below image ;

[image]

if you go for 2nd or 3rd page you will see as below image ;

[image]

replace old values here and save and than clear cache and check in private window.....

Comment: i have done this also in these columns i have values like this "{{unsecure_base_url}}media/"

Comment: @AbhishekJain please check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-do-i-fix-my-base-urls-so-i-can-access-my-magento-site

Comment: hey i have make these changes also but sill its not working.

Comment: @AbhishekJain please take your database backup first, than try other things, check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280049/how-can-i-fix-the-unsecure-base-url-on-my-magento-installation

Comment: can i have your email id so that i can share my hosting credential with you.

Comment: @AbhishekJain if you share hosting credentials also i have no other idea to solve the problem, sorry for that, also as Fiasco Labs commented : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-do-i-fix-my-base-urls-so-i-can-access-my-magento-site , you can try restrating server . also you can post question here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/ with what you tried so that you may get help soon.....